# Row does not match id - JQGrid

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid

I'm working with JQgrid and I have the problem that the rows do not match the id row, it goes down one position and also the last row is repeated, I don't know where to start checking, any idea?
here is an example image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbkQG.jpg)

Comment: Please, tell us the version of jqgrid and if possible publish your code and data. The best will be if you prepare a demo. In most cases it seems that there is a problem with the definition of the **id** in jsonReader or you maybe need to set it in colModel. In all cases we need code and test data.

Comment: Thanks, reviewing a bit, I discovered that the problem occurs when adding the search row or filters, I don't know if it's a bug, when I remove this element, the problem disappears, but I am left without this filter bar in the grid, so the I am adding:

jQuery("#datosCondXSol").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { defaultSearch: 'cn' });